Is there actually a "welcome culture" here?
I wonder what some users or moderators do here (in Stack Overflow):
I had asked a question, but got no comments.
Instead, I got two close votes and one down-vote, still without any comment.
Well, I'm a long-time user here, so I can stand it, but I wonder what new users should think about such.
Question asked: Timer "OnUnitInactiveSec=1day" is not triggered as expected
Shouldn't there be a "welcome culture" for questions?

I wonder what new users should think about such. ... Shouldn't here be a "welcome culture" for questions?" You mean the Staging Ground?

As for your question, that doesn't look like it's on topic for [so]. It looks more like it's on topic for [unix.se]. (The other two votes were to migrate it to [su] and here, Meta (clearly wrong).)

Is this a complaint about not getting comments with the votes? Are you looking for help in understanding why was the question not well-received? Just a rant? What would "welcome culture" have to do with anything here?

I didn't see "Staging Ground" before.. On the topic: The timer is part of a program package that is to be delivered, so I think it's a valid programming question (assuming that systemd units are a kind of programming language). I think that down-voting questions or closing questions without a comment giving the OP a chance to react on such make the user be frustrated and go away. And making the user go away is the opposite for welcome culture IMHO.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr

@yivi I just got the opposite impression than "Contrary to popular opinion, most users here are kind and want to help rather than enjoying "shooting down" newbies' questions with downvotes to make them feel bad and unwelcome. " - Maybe it's just that downvoting (or close-voting) is so much faster than writing some words. - Many times I had the impression that some powerful users act according to "I don't like this question, so let's close it" - IMHO if you don't like a question or don't understand it, skip it (and leave the decision to others).

Do not assume users how use their votes "do not understand" the post they are voting. Voting is simply a way to express the opinion "I think this content is useful here", or the opposite. We are supposed to use our votes, to help other users more quickly identify the more useful content (and to help to make it easier to get rid of content that's not really useful around here). Abstaining from voting when the opinion is negative is not really helpful, and contrary to how the site is meant to operate.

Interestingly expressing an opinion without giving reasoning is exactly the reason why "AI answers" are unwanted, isn't it? ;-)

No, it's not. This is completely unrelated.

"Maybe it's just that downvoting (or close-voting) is so much faster than writing some words." It is faster, as we wait zero seconds for a user to improve their question. A user may choose to comment, but there are many reasons why we don't and on closure the user gets a banner explaining the reason for closure, if it ends up closed.

To be clear: you feel unwelcome because your off-topic question was judged as off topic? "IMHO it's hard to argue that the first one is not a programming problem, while the second one is." - I don't understand your reasoning. Can you please tell me, the name of the programming language that needs to be used to solve the problem?

"Shouldn't there be a "welcome culture" for questions?" - no, only for good questions. What tends to take people by surprise is that Stack Overflow has strict quality rules, but... that's the whole point for the site existing. So when you search using Google/Bing/Etc., Stack Overflow pops up in the top X search results with actual valuable information. If we would be "welcoming" to literally any question someone dumps onto the site that process would be severely broken.

I'm a bit late to the party.  Why does OP's original question have 11 downvotes?  Sure, it would be better suited to Super User, but the question's quality doesn't at all seem that bad (unless it underwent significant editing).

@AndyJ it's almost certainly due to the Meta Effect.  Which is...unfortunate; it's probably off-topic, but not nearly as bad as a typical question that receives a score that low.

If anything, at least relatively speaking comparing to other sites on the web, Stack Exchange culture on the main sites (chat and meta can be a different story depending on definition) is pretty anti-social (in the sense of just having some alignment on some discipline and design in keeping noise low in signal-to-noise, and some degree of systematic anonymity). Up/down votes are anonymous, comments have a fairly specific purpose, and noise in general (anything that is not an attempt to be useful content) is discouraged or removed.
If those are your definition of unwelcoming, some attitude shift / alignment is in order, or this may not be the site for you.
I think the culture we'd like to have (maybe in a more wishful/idealistic sense) is "lurk a little more, maybe?". Like: "read the Help Center and learn the platform's rules, guidelines, norms, and etiquette; and then start engaging with the platform".
I hope I can speak on behalf of the average person here and say we welcome people who do that. Or more conservatively, we welcome on-topic, useful content.

The word "antisocial" has several meanings, some of which are affirmatively pretty negative ("hostile or harmful to organized society").  I don't believe that's what you mean (perhaps "unsociable" may convey your intended meaning less ambiguously), so you may wish to clarify.

@RyanM huh. I don't know what word to use then. weirdly, for me, "anti-social" has a more neutral connotation and "unsociable" has a more negative connotation. in any case, I've tried to explain what I mean a little more clearly.

"asocial" is another possibility.  Your edit does help to clarify, though.

Most new users can't see close votes on their own question so they won't notice them until their question is closed - as yours now is. Once a question is closed it receives a notice explaining why it is closed. Until that point there's no notice as without a quorum of close voters we don't take their votes as gospel.
Since your question isn't really about programming, but about system configuration it doesn't belong here, which is why it's now closed. I imagine the downvotes are down to that too i.e. you should have researched where to ask this question more thoroughly e.g. by reading the systemd tag info...

Systemd is a system management daemon designed for Linux. Use this tag for programming questions using systemd or its libraries. Questions about configuring the daemon (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.


Maybe I should have pointed out that the timer added is part of a programming project that includes a utility and systemd services to run those automatically. Then I think it is a programming question. And: It's always hard to find the correct forum between Linux&UNIX, Super User and Stack Overflow. Wouldn't the existence of tag systemd-timer indicate that questions about systemd timers are valid?

The article tag was burninated previously, it's back now but that doesn't make it any more of a valid tag than it was when it was burninated.

"It's always hard to find the correct forum" None of them are forums, @U.Windl . None of the sites in the network work like forums (the closest thing is the (failure of a) feature, Discussions, and even that isn't a forum). Don't treat the sites like a forum, as doing so will result in a poorer user experience.

"Wouldn't the existence of tag systemd-timer indicate that questions about systemd timers are valid?" No, the existence of a tag doesn't mean you can ask anything about that topic; the question still needs to be on-topic according to the site's guidelines. There is a [[tag:windows]] tag, and a [[tag:firefox]] tag, however, that doesn't mean I can ask questions on [so] about how to change my desktop background, delete my browsing history, or if I should have double or triple glazed windows in my living room.

@U.Windl: part of a programming project does not mean the question is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

@U.Windl: When decide topic-ness of a question, it is useful to read description of the tags used in that question. E.g. description of the tag [tag:systemd] clearly says that "Questions about configuring the daemon (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.".

"Maybe I should have pointed out that the timer added is part of a programming project " - This still does not make it a programming question. Making configuration changes to systemd is NOT a programming question.

"Maybe I should have pointed out that the timer added is part of a programming project that includes a utility and systemd services to run those automatically. " Do you use a programming language, yourself to implement the timer? In what sense is the timer "part of" your "programming project" that could not equally well be said of, say, the computer itself?

"Wouldn't the existence of tag systemd-timer indicate that questions about systemd timers are valid?" No, not any more than the fact that Wikipedia has a list of Labrador Retrievers means you should be able to add your own. See also; see also.

Yes, we welcome new questions as long as they are on-topic, well-written and non-duplicate. We are very happy to receive more of such questions.
Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, so we don't focus on the users. We expect them to be very familiar with the help center and our guidelines. But we don't treat users with disrespect either. We understand that users are the ones who contribute to the site and we welcome new users that want to contribute here.
Some of the ways we welcome users are Staging Ground and edits to their posts to improve grammar, spelling, and remove noise. Voting doesn't play any role in being welcoming though. We judge content with other users in mind and not the poster. The poster can use the votes as a form of feedback and improve their question if they see primarily negative votes. They can choose to ignore votes altogether too.
Users can add comments to request more information from the user but this is orthogonal to voting and closing. We are encouraged to ask for clarification in comments if we believe a question can be improved when such information is added to it. With the volume of questions we receive don't expect to receive such comments outside of staging ground.
